# JOIN Modification

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preview of tables I am working with:

For example/context:

Table Name: [GMC Claims 2019]

| **PName** | **HSSV** | **DateOfService** | **InsName** | **DRG** | **RevCode** | **CPT** | **Qty** | **BilledCharges** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Hisham | SIP | 5 | BCBS | 870 | 344 | 44 | 15 |
| 5 | Hisham | SIP | 5 | BCBS | 0 | 440 | 70 | 69 |
| 5 | Hisham | SIP | 5 | BCBS | 0 | 440 | 70 | 69 |
| 5 | Hisham | SIP | 5 | BCBS | 0 | 419 | 70 | 69 |

Table Name: BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS

| DRG Code | Description | DRG Weight | ALOS | High Trim | Effective Date | DRG Rate | Per Diem High Trim Outlier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | XXXXX | YYYYY | 30 | 54 | 10/1/2018 | $235,121.59 | $5,486.17 |
| 101 | XXXXX | YYYYY | 24 | 40 | 10/1/2018 | $146,736.72 | $4,279.82 |
| 870 | XXXX | YYYYY | 13 | 23 | 10/1/2018 | $80894.61 | $3934.56 |

Table Name: [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016]

| DRG | SERVICE | PMT (SDA) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | DRG CARVE OUT | 13537 |
| 439 | DRG CARVE OUT | 13537 |

My Current Code:

```
SELECT
DRG, DRG_Rate,BilledCharges,'TotalPmt'=

CASE
    
 WHEN BilledCharges>275000
              THEN BilledCharges-275000*0.195+0
               ELSE NULL
              END 
              
FROM
    [GMC Claims 2019]

JOIN BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS 
        ON [GMC Claims 2019].DRG = BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.DRG_Code
LEFT JOIN [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016] 
        ON [GMC Claims 2019].DRG = [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016]. DRG_c
```

Output of my current code:

| **DRG_Rate** | **BilledCharges** | **TotalPmt** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 870 | 80894.61 | 485000 |

My goal:

I need the sum of Billed Charges in the [GMC Claims 2019] table to be used in my calculation in my above query, not just the individual line item Billed Charges. Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to modify my join statement?

In plain English, this is what I want my case statement to read: "If the sum of billed charges for patient 5 from the GMC table > 275,000, THEN TotalPmt is = sum of billed charges for patient 5 (which is $1,209,350.52) - 275000 * 0.195 + DRG_Rate in my current output (80894.61) to **EQUAL $263,092.96**

That's the number that should be in the TotalPmt column in my final output. The Sum of billed charges in the first table is the only piece I am missing to make this work.

Any tips/advice would be appreciated!

Comment: markdown issues with the billed charges.... shows right in edit mode. total billed charges should equal 1209350.52

Comment: You're going to have to be more explicit, those column names are gibberish. When you say "sum", what is your `group by`, you don't seem to have one?